# NuGet Package Restore Issue

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I need NuGet to automatically restore packages. At the moment, the referenced dlls are missing.

I have enabled `package restore` on my solution.

The `.nuget` folder is checked in.

The `packages.config` file is checked in for each project.

The `packages` folder (on solution level) is check in.

The `packages` folder contains folders for all the packages the solution uses with `nuspec` and `nupkg` files for each package. The `dll` is not checked in.

In `VisualStudio` the packages are installed but the reference to the dll in each project is missing (ass the dll is not checked in).

I have tried to install `NuGetPowerTools`. Same story.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to check-in anything underneath the packages folder. Optionally, you can check in the repositories.config file but technically this is not required.

Do I get it right that you have checked-in the nuspec and nupkg files within the Packages folder? if so, delete them. These will be restored, and their presence might be causing restore failures (I don't think NuGet package restore is checking for the presence of the package contents, and rather checks for the presence of the nupkg/nuspec file in the Packages folder, skipping the package from being restored if found)

In summary, check in only:

1. The empty solution level `packages` folder (optionally the `repositories.config`)
2. `.nuget` folder and its contents
3. `packages.config` for every project

Comment: So the only files (and folders) NuGet related that are to be checked in are the empty solution level packages `folder` and each project's `packages.config` file? Am I correct?

Comment: Correct, only empty Packages folder (optionally the repositories.config) and all packages.config files + .nuget folder should be checked in.

Comment: I've edited your answer with a short summary, I hope this is okay.

Answer (score 1):

I have got this problem in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Found a [solution](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1656768/installing-certain-nuget-packages-fails-to-actually-extract-the-dll-files-to-the-relevant-lib-folder-and-fails-to-add-an-assembly-reference-to-the-csproj-file) that worked for me:

> Went in to the user profile NuGet cache
>   (`C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\`), and deleted everything in
>   there.
>
> I think during the restore process my cache was cleared of all DLL
>   files, and when I tried to install a package it was using the cache
>   instead of the files off of NuGet. Now that I've cleared the cache, I
>   can now install the NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the same symptoms as I had once, and then the cause was the permission level on `packages.config`. Deleting the file solved it for me.

I have no idea if it will help you, but have a look at the permission sets for all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, deleted config and re-referenced all the packages. Think it has something to do with SVN.